# Android app shows Blank screen of Google map v2 with zoom button and google logo

Tags: android, google-maps

I integrate google map v2  in my android app. it show blank screen with zoom button and google logo.
its saved instance is also null. I signed my app with debug certificate now but at fist i signed with release.store. before it was show error like not contact with google server. when i signed app  with
debug.store it shows response in adb like

**map = com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@4b14c078**

**aid = com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a@4b14c070**

**aic = null**

Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bilawalkhan.pakistanmap" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCLgSPDsNfVrGFPO2636kWMXIAaZu2f43p"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main_Activity is

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
   GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
```

map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Map">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

its debugger shows like this.

```
map = com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@4b14c078
aid = com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a@4b14c070
>aic = null
```

Logcat shows:

```
10-29 18:40:44.200    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-29 18:40:44.200    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
10-29 18:40:45.640    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ Http Status Code: 200
10-29 18:40:45.640    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ IMAppDatabaseManager->deleteEvents
10-29 18:40:45.640    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ Ping Response: {"success":true}
10-29 18:40:45.700    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@4b0914ec
10-29 18:40:45.720    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.d.h@4b22898c
10-29 18:40:45.730    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.o@4b22bce8
10-29 18:40:45.820    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Processing DataRequest: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@4afd6518
10-29 18:40:45.820    3621-3795/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=22, status: fb, data: 1510
10-29 18:40:45.830    3621-3795/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=22, status: lb, data: 1630
10-29 18:40:45.830    3621-3795/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/USER_EVENTS﹕ Event: type=22, status: flbs, data: fb=1510|lb=1630|s=1100
10-29 18:40:45.830    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(0): 62|75|75|147, 1s, 1kb
10-29 18:40:45.830    3621-3806/com.bilawalkhan.maptesting D/REQUEST﹕ Close
10-29 18:41:08.790    1898-2812/com.bluestacks.bstfolder D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 606K, 24% free 2686K/3508K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-29 18:41:15.690    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ NetworkManager->handleMessag: msg:{ when=-40ms what=1001 target=android.os.Handler }
10-29 18:41:15.700    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ IMAppDatabaseManager->getEvents
10-29 18:41:15.710    1958-2182/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.4.3﹕ PayloadBuilder->getPayloadList:
10-29 18:41:53.870    1898-2812/com.bluestacks.bstfolder D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 606K, 24% free 2678K/3508K, paused 0ms, total 0m
```

Comment: `I integrate google map v2 in my android app` .... me too, and it works for me ...

Comment: please read [ask] ;)

Comment: but its not work for me

Comment: ok next time ask question like programmer :P

Comment: Em new in stack and orgramming thats why i dont know how to ask

Comment: plzz give me the solution of my problem

Comment: @mithrop  I really very thankful to you

Comment: please [ask] and maybe I will try to understand your question. here, I don't understand even what it's wrong. We do not owe you anything : YOU have to make an effort to help us to understand your problem and then we will try to find you a solution.

Comment: Em sure now the Question is capable to undertand..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this:

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 21.3235752;
            double longitude =74.1881265;

            // lets place some 10 random markers

                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title(" Mapview Test ");



                    //marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions and API**

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mapexdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- meta-data before </application> tag -->
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDxEkfvGvKy.........your api key" />

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: After using your code above log occcurs as i mentioned above

Comment: same blank screen come on app

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. You should tailor each answer *specifically* to the issues in the question If the questions can be answered by the exact same answer, they should possibly be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Krupa's Patel code is absolutely fine and works perfectly, what you have done wrong is :

.... a blank screen without any grid, with a google logo on your bottom left hand-side means that most probably the API key that you created is not the appropriate one ; You should not create a simple API key but one which registers your application for Google Maps Android API in Google Developers Console.The proper link drives you to the "Enable an API page", here the link https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapiapiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true